# How can I read this Terraform cycle error message to find the cyclic references?

Tags: terraform

I get this surprising error message from Terraform, and although I in theory understand what the problem is about I can't quite figure out how to read the output and find the problematic cycle. I don't understand why some of them are flagged as *(expand)* or *(destroy)* and I have not managed to find details in Terraform docs. Does anyone have a quick guide to reading this "cycle stack trace"?

```
Error: Cycle: module.cloudrun["api"].google_cloud_run_service_iam_policy.noauth (destroy deposed 6540c050), module.cloudrun["admin"].google_cloud_run_service_iam_policy.noauth, module.loadbalancer.google_compute_region_network_endpoint_group.cloudrun_endpoint["admin"] (destroy deposed 7447d6a8), module.loadbalancer.google_compute_region_network_endpoint_group.cloudrun_endpoint (expand), module.loadbalancer.google_compute_region_network_endpoint_group.cloudrun_endpoint["admin"], module.cloudrun["admin"].google_cloud_run_service_iam_policy.noauth (destroy deposed 3867bbeb), module.cloudrun["admin"].google_cloud_run_service.service (destroy), module.loadbalancer.google_compute_region_network_endpoint_group.cloudrun_endpoint["api"], module.loadbalancer.google_compute_region_network_endpoint_group.cloudrun_endpoint["api"] (destroy deposed 8036362d), module.cloudrun["api"].google_cloud_run_service.service (destroy), module.cloudrun["api"].google_cloud_run_service_iam_policy.noauth, module.cloudrun (close), module.loadbalancer.var.cloudrun_services (expand), module.loadbalancer.local.cloudrun_services (expand)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the output of the plan and apply command is quite bad when it comes to identifying cycles. One option is to install `graphviz` and run the following command:

`terraform graph -draw-cycles | dot -Tsvg > graph.svg`.

This will give you something visual and more readable. Note that if your terraform is sufficiently complicated, even this output will be quite unreadable.

Comment: I guess there isn't currently any better answer than this, so I will accept it. Maybe Terraform devs will improve this someday..